# Web worker usage in jsp page

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I have one small poc project in which i am using spring MVC and javascript. To start the project i call

http://127.0.0.1:8080/POC/start

The above request will be handled by MVC controller and it will return a start.jsp page in which my html and javascript codes are present which make the UI and handle user input request.

Now, i want to use web worker for heavy task handling. I have created a worker.js file at same location where start.jsp file is there and added the heavy operation related codes. In start.jsp file i am calling

var w = new Worker("worker.js")

but it gives an error as GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/POC/worker.js 404 (Not Found)

I am new to javascript programming so not able to handle this error. 
Any help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with JavaScript. Your `worker.js` file isn't on the path `http://127.0.0.1:8080/POC/`, which is where the relative URL `worker.js` says it will be when used on a page whose URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8080/POC/start`. So you'll need to put it on that path in your deployment (so that `http://127.0.0.1:8080/POC/worker.js` is found), or adjust the relative path you're using with `new Worker` to resolve to the correct URL for the file.